# Is it wrong to do tar czf somename.tar some_*_files?

Tags: tar, filenames, gzip

Is it wrong to do `tar czf somname.tar some_*_files` instead of `tar czf somname.tar.gz some_*_files`, then of course `tar xf somename.tar`? That is : without adding the `.gz` extension.

This question is purely about not adding the `.gz` extension to the filename `somename.tar` and if this comes with any unexpected side-effects.  *This question is Not about the use of `-z`.*

Comment: Try it on a single file. Does it work?

Comment: You can give it pretty much any name, eg `archive.box` as long as you can remember what it means...

Comment: @don_crissti I think the question related to the use of `-z` when creating the archive and the lack of it when attempting to extract files. I've suggested the OP simply tries it

Comment: Yes, it does work. But I do worry that (when) breaking conventions might come with unexpected side-effects. Hence the question.

Comment: @roaima No, it is not about -z. It is "known" that `tar xf` == `tar xzf`. No need for `-z`. The question is purely about the extension.

Comment: I'd say it's bad form to have a `...tar.gz` file without the `.gz` as it might be a `tar --lzma` file but ultimately `tar` can figure all that out on its own. Functionally it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Nikos Alexandris your question doesn't say that you're asking about the extension rather than the use of `-z`. Please make your question clearer so that the right answer can be given. Nevertheless my original comments still stands - try it and see.

Comment: @roaima I will. However, I ask ".. that is : without adding the .gz extension."

Answer (score 2):

You can name the tarball anything you like. For example,

```
tar czvf surprise.c /etc/hosts 2>/dev/null

file surprise.c
surprise.c: gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 10240
```

You may find that a GUI expects such files to be suffixed with `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`, and if I were looking for a compressed tarball I'd expect it to have one of those two suffixes, but the system itself doesn't worry.

Conclusion? Use conventional suffixes to provide informational hints about the file contents. In the case of `tar`, use `.tar` for an uncompressed archive and either `.tgz` or `.tar.gz` for a `gzip`-compressed archive.

Comment: Beware that to name the tar ball `-`, you have to write it `tar czf ./- files` or `tar cf - files | gzip > -` as with `tar czf - files`, `tar` would interpret that `-` as meaning stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Omitting the `.gz` from the end of a filename does not prevent a `tar cz` command from writing the output file in compressed form, and it does not prevent most GNU `tar x` commands from automatically detecting the input file is compressed and de-compressing it.  I.e., the computer doesn't need you to have the `.gz` on the end of the filename to know how to work with the file.

So your question boils down to how you communicate with other people about the contents of the file.  They are the ones who might be confused by the lack of `.gz` on the filename and do the wrong thing with it.  (sometimes, if months pass between creating the file and unpacking it, those "other people" can be **you**)

If it's important for other people to see the `.gz`. to know the file is compressed, then include it.  If it's not very important, then you can omit it.

Answer (score 1):

At least for GNU `tar` (which is the only `tar` I'm familiar with) *as long as you specify the compression option* I don't think the extensions matter when you are extracting with `tar xf`.
Let's omit the second extension (`xz`):

```
tar cJf archive.tar  pic*.jpg
file archive.tar
```

```
archive.tar: XZ compressed data, checksum CRC64
```

and the first one (`tar`):

```
tar cJf archive  pic*.jpg
file archive
```

```
archive: XZ compressed data, checksum CRC64
```

Let's use `jpg` extension:

```
tar cJf archive.jpg  pic*.jpg
file archive.jpg
```

```
archive.jpg: XZ compressed data, checksum CRC64
```

Let's use `tar.gz` extension but still compress with `xz`:

```
tar cJf archive.tar.gz  pic*.jpg
file archive.tar.gz
```

```
archive.tar.gz: XZ compressed data, checksum CRC64
```

As you can see, in all cases, `tar` correctly archived and compressed the files (with `xz`), irrespective of the name of the archive. The extension does make a difference if you use `--auto-compress`... i.e. if you provide an extension that is supported, it will use the right compressor

```
tar caf archive.tar.xz  pic*.jpg
file archive.tar.xz
```

```
archive.tar.xz: XZ compressed data, checksum CRC64
```

whereas if it doesn't recognize the extension (or if you use `tar`) it will create an uncompressed `tar` archive:

```
tar caf archive.bag pic*.jpg
file archive.bag
```

```
archive.bag: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

Regardless, in all cases, `tar xf` will extract the files, as the manual explains:

> Reading compressed archive is even simpler: you don’t need to specify
> any additional options as GNU tar recognizes its format automatically.
> Thus, the following commands will list and extract the archive created
> in previous example:
>
> ```
> # List the compressed archive
> $ tar tf archive.tar.gz
> # Extract the compressed archive
> $ tar xf archive.tar.gz
> ```
>
> The format recognition algorithm is based on signatures, a special
> byte sequences in the beginning of file, that are specific for certain
> compression formats...If this approach fails, tar falls back to using
> archive name suffix to determine its format (see auto-compress, for a
> list of recognized suffixes).

Is it good practice not using extensions? No. As other people have said, the main goal here is clarity.

Comment: FWIW, `tar cf - a | gzip | xz | bzip2 | zstd > b; bsdtar tf b` works fine. No need for file extension or telling it what decompressor to use.